# Angular won't load background image when added in HTML Style

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

I have this image path `<div>{{image}}</div>` which gives:

```
<div>http://my_ip/images/file.jpg</div>
```

but when I add this in my HTML as a style background, it doesn't load!

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{image}}')"></div>
```

gives

```
<div style></div>
```

Any idea what's going on here? Why isn't Angular rendering the image as a background image?

Edit: I'm using Angular 4.

Comment: ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+image+')'}"

Comment: `ng-style` is not working in AngularJS 4 anymore. I have tried this but it isn't working: `style="{'background-image':'url({{image}}.jpg)'}"`

Comment: What is `+image+` in place of the curly bracket? I have tried that but it won't render.

Comment: You're using AngularJS right? Versioning (<= 1.6) and not Angular (the newer flavor, Version 2, 4, etc..).

Comment: I'm using Angular 4.

Comment: I believe the syntax is [ngStyle] then. Try creating a plunkr so that somebody can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Use this directive binding syntax

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+backgroundUrl+')'}"
```

where background url is the link to your url address. This is documented here 
https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: What is `+backgroundUrl+`? I tried `+image+` in place of `{{image}}` but nothing happens

Comment: backgroundUrl is a variable defined in your component. It is a string with the url you're displaying.

Comment: Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular4, there are couple of ways to do inline CSS. Easiest one is to import and use ngStyle  `[ngStyle]`  (old AngularJS syntax is ng-style) directive from the common package.

The other way is to do property binding on the component directly using `[style.{attribute}]`, which in your case: `[style.backgroundImage]`.

Documents can be found here:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/60/Angular-4-CSS-Tutorial